# SQL Query Ignoring Condition

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sqlite

So Im trying to "List all the Books that are written by author Gale and are printed by a Pocket Books"

My DB tables are as follows

```
Table: author 
authorNumber, authorName
         01         Gale
         02         Ben
Table: book
bookCode,  bookTitle,     publishCode
     189   Press & Trash  PB
    3743   Ecommerce      PB

Table: publisher
publisherCode, publisherName
      PB        Pocket Books
      BB        Batman Books

Table: wrote
bookCode,  authorNumber
     189     01
     3743    02
```

This is my Query, Its ignoring my Gale conditon and just getting all books published by Pocket Books, any help?

```
SELECT bookTitle
FROM Book B, Wrote BC, Author, Publisher PC
WHERE B.bookCode = BC.bookCode
AND B.publisherCode = PC.publisherCode
AND authorName ='Gale'
AND publisherName ='Pocket Books'
GROUP BY bookTitle;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add the join conditon for `author`. You better use the explicit join syntax which makes that more visible.

```
SELECT B.bookTitle
FROM Book B
join Wrote BC on B.bookCode = BC.bookCode
join Author A on BC.authorNumber = A.authorNumber
join Publisher PC on B.publisherCode = PC.publisherCode
WHERE A.authorName ='Gale'
AND PC.publisherName ='Pocket Books'
GROUP BY B.bookTitle
```

And you don't need to group also.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing one join `BC.authorNumber=Author.authorNumber`:

```
SELECT bookTitle
FROM Book B, Wrote BC, Author, Publisher PC
WHERE B.bookCode = BC.bookCode
AND B.publisherCode = PC.publisherCode
AND BC.authorNumber=Author.authorNumber
AND authorName ='Gale'
AND publisherName ='Pocket Books'
GROUP BY bookTitle;`
```